# Use a batch script to replace a double backslash in XML

Tags: xml, batch-file

I have an xml file with the following:

`<setParameter value="\\deveserver\d$\Websites\anime" name="IIS Web Application Name"/>`

I want to write a batch script that will search for this `\\deveserver\d$\Websites\anime` string (which is saved in a variable, called `CurrentFolder`) and replace it with whatever input that was entered.

I saved the entered path in variable, `DestinationFolder`

```
SET DestinationFldr=
SET /p DestinationFldr=Enter Destination path:
```

Any replace and text posts that I checked doesn't seem to work. I think it's not able to recognize the double backslash.  Please help.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@ECHO off
SETLOCAL
SET "currentfolder=\\deveserver\d$\Websites\anime"
SET "DestinationFldr=some\variety\of\input"
(
FOR /f "delims=" %%i IN ('type aninput.xml^|findstr /n /r "$" ') DO (
 SET line=%%i
  SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
  SET line=!line:*:=!
  IF DEFINED line (ECHO(!line:%currentfolder%=%destinationfldr%!) ELSE (ECHO()
  endlocal
)
)>anoutput.xml

FC aninput.xml anoutput.xml
```

Setting `currentfolder` as specified and `destfldr` to some string to simulate input,

- read each line into `%%i` and number it with leading `number :` - including
  empty lines
- assign the value to `line`
- start a setlocal delayedexpansion frame
- remove the part of `line` up to and including the first colon (ie the line number inserted by `findstr`
- if `line` is still defined, `echo` it with the string substituted; else `echo` a blank line
- close the setlocal frame

FC inputfile outputfile to show changes

Comment: @user2283170 If that worked for you, it is expected that you will upvote the answer and then "accept" it (click the check-mark below the votes).

Answer (score 0):

If you have `<setParameter value="\\deveserver\d$\Websites\anime" name="IIS Web Application Name"/>` in `file.xml` you can use this code:

```
@echo off&setlocal
set "CurrentFolder=\\deveserver\d$\Websites\anime"

for /f "delims=" %%i in (file.xml) do set "html=%%i"
SET DestinationFldr=
SET /p "DestinationFldr=Enter Destination path: "
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set "html=!html:%CurrentFolder%=%DestinationFldr%!"
echo html: !html!
```

Test & output:

```
Enter Destination path: \\myserver\&&\othersites\adele
html: <setParameter value="\\myserver\&&\othersites\adele" name="IIS Web Application Name"/>
```